# Let $ V $ be open in a metric space $ (X,d) $. Show that, for all $ A⊂X $, $ V∩\overline{A}⊂\overline{A∩V} $.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

> Definition: If $ X $ is a metric space, $ E \subset X $ and $ E '$ represents the set of all limit points of $ E $ in $ X $, then let us denote the closure of $ E $ as $ \overline {E} = E \cup E '. $

Let $ V $ be an open in a metric space $ (X,d) $. Show that for all $ A⊂X $ we have $ V∩\overline{A}⊂\overline{A∩V} $.

**My attempt.**
Let $ x \in V \cap \overline {A} $, then $ x \in V $ and $ x \in \overline {A} $. Let us consider two cases:

- If $x\in A$ and $x\in V$, then $x\in V\cap A\subset \overline{A\cap V}$. Since for any set $ A $ we have $ A \subset \overline {A} $.
- If $x\in A'$ and $x\in V$. Since $ x \in A '$, there exists $ q \neq x $ such that $ q \in A $. Since $ V $ is open, then all its points are limits, that is, $ q \in V $. Therefore, $ q \in V \cap A $, that is $ x \in \overline {V \cap A} $.

Comment: By the way, in current English, what you call "lock" (the union of a set and its limit points) is "closure"...

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to English. I am studying this language, and I am not very familiar yet :). But is my prove good?

Comment: Your second bullet is not convincing.  Why should $q \in V$?

Answer (score 3):

No, the proof is not correct.

The division into cases is good and the proof for the first case is OK.

If $x\in A'$ and $x\in V$, then you want to show that $x\in(V\cap A)'$.

Take a neighborhood $U$ of $x$. Then also $U\cap V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and, by definition of limit point, there is $y\in (U\cap V)\cap A=U\cap(V\cap A)$, $y\ne x$. Thus $y\in V\cap A$ and this proves that $x\in (V\cap A)'$. Note that, by definition, $(V\cap A)'\subseteq\overline{V\cap A}$, so the proof is complete.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Done (almost) as requested. I'm asking *why* people complicate their life by defining the closure this way.

Comment: great! Much better now. Yeah a lot of questions here use this definition of closure, which is a weird anachronism, it takes us back to the early 20th century when things were still done that way. Traditions die hard..